# Scrapy hidden information from stock of iPhone in the Apple Stores

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to scrapy stock information for iPhone in the Apple Stores:

https://reserve.cdn-apple.com/ES/es_ES/reserve/iPhone/availability

This information is hidden in the div class "dropdown-container hidden" until you choose a model and a store.

How can i get info by scrapy?

Comment: Have you tried anything? How does your spider look currently?

Comment: No, i do not know how to view content that is initially hidden.

Comment: Check your browser's Dev Tools "Network" tab: the info you need is in https://reserve.cdn-apple.com/ES/es_ES/reserve/iPhone/stores.json , https://reserve.cdn-apple.com/ES/es_ES/reserve/iPhone/availability.json and iPhone model numbers are in a Javascript variable called `RPData`

Answer (score 1):

Apple website has expressed that they doesn't like what you are doing I suggest you take the hint.

First You can try to get some information using scrapy shell.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) to crawl this kind of page.

it can simulate browser behavior to get what you want.